# Can’t change developer website in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Dose anyone know how the edit/remove my developer website in the new google play console? the ‎new console doesn’t have a website field in the account details anymore, there is no way to change ‎the URL I provided when I first created my developer ‎account, the new Google Play console only ‎allows me to change the website of the developer page.‎

I need to change my developer website that I provided when I first created my developer ‎account ‎‎“trackaty.com” because it’s currently owned by someone else who is redirect it to a gambling website ‎which prevents me from updating any of my apps.‎

I tried to find out who registered my old domain, and I find out the new owner registered it from a ‎Chinese company called Xin Net Technology, I thing they are famous for supporting spammers. ‎

I even thought about transferring all my apps to a new developer account, but [the documentation ‎states](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-download-reports-you-may-need-later%2Cstep-make-sure-your-google-play-developer-accounts-are-registered-and-active%2Cstep-find-the-target-account-transaction-id%2Cstep-review-policy-guidelines) that the original account and all the apps need to comply with all policy guidelines before ‎transferring anything, which solves nothing.‎

It worth to mention that few of my old removed apps by me used to link to trackaty.com, but the ‎email I get says the problem is in the developer website, I guess that means it’s the account website ‎itself not any of my old removed apps.‎

So, dose anyone faced a similar problem or know how you change the developer website?‎

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when trying to add developer website for adding app-ads.txt file. It seems that they changed its place in new Google Play Console. And developer page menu is confusing developers. Adding my website to developer page didn't work.

So here it is in new Play Console : When you choose a specific app in Google Play Console, click **Store Settings** on the left panel. You'll see **Store Listing Contact Details** and there you'll find a box for **website**.

Comment: This will change the website of the selected app in google play listing, my problem is the developer website that i entered when i created my account.

Selected App-> Store Settings-> Store listing contact details-> Website (changes the app website)
All apps-> Developer page-> Website address (changes the website of developer page)

The old console used to have this option to:
All apps-> Account details-> Website address (changes the developer website) but unfortunately this option doesn't exist anymore.

Anyway i had to create a new developer account and migrate all my apps to it.

Answer (score 0):

The developer website can be modified from the Play Console. Go to menu `Settings > Developer account > Developer page` then you'll see an optional field `Website address`.

[image: Screenshot of the developer page in Play Console]

When you update this field, it may take a few days to be reflected in the Play Store.

Comment: I know there is a website field in the developer page @peter, but it doesn't effect the developer website, actually my updates was rejected before i even created a developer page. I created my developer page after the rejection just to try to change my developer website but it didn't solve the problem. I believe the old console used to have a website filed in the account details and in developer page too.